# Setting transparent background for activity shown as dialog on xml not working on all devices

Tags: android, android-styles, android-background

I have a custom view on an activity that is showed as a dialog.
I applied a custom theme to my activity so its parent is: "@android:style/Theme.Dialog" and I changed the window background to be transparent.

My Manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.rev.revcorder.ui.UserAuthenticationDialogActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/userAuthenticationDialog">
</activity>
```

My styles.xml:

```
<style name="userAuthenticationDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

The issue is that it is working fine on my device (Nexus 4 running 4.4) but on other device that is the same as mine (Nexus 4 running 4.4) it is not. Instead, the background is shown in black not transparent.

It only worked when I set it grammatically by adding:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00000000")));
```

My question is, what is the difference between setting the window background on my xml style and doing i grammatically ?
Also, how come it is working on my device and not on another same device ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Add 2 more attributes to style like below code:

```
<style name="userAuthenticationDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `Custom Theme` for all the devices.

For example, here is the declaration for a custom theme which is simply the standard platforms default light theme. It would go in an XML file under `res/values` (typically `res/values/styles.xml`):

```
<style name="LightThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Light">
...
</style>
```

To have this theme use the newer holographic theme when the application is running on `Android 3.0 (API Level 11) or higher`, you can place an alternative declaration for the theme in an XML file in `res/values-v11`, but make the parent theme the holographic theme:

```
<style name="LightThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
...
```

Now use this theme like you would any other, and your application will automatically switch to the holographic theme if running on Android 3.0 or higher.

For more information about providing alternative resources, such as `themes and layouts`, based on the platform version or other device configurations, see the [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) document.

Show below image how can u structure resources.

[image]

**Update:**

Also try this, set below `Theme` into manifest.xml

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: The problem is not about API level. Both devices are running Android 4.4
I need the activity view to be transparent and to be displayed as a dialog, that is why I am using  "@android:style/Theme.Dialog"